# MySql SelecT CASE WHEN THEN SELECT

Tags: case

i have a problem, if anyone could help me, problem " Subquery returns more than 1 row "

I need to select the drivers for the dropdown field,
if driving for Van then selects only Van drivers
if driving for Kombi then selects Kombi and Van drivers
if driving for Limo then selects all drivers

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN "Van"="Van"      
THEN (SELECT fahrername FROM fahrer WHERE auto = 'Van')
WHEN "Kombi"="Kombi"
THEN  (SELECT fahrername FROM fahrer WHERE auto = 'Kombi' AND auto = 'Van')
ELSE  (SELECT fahrername FROM fahrer)
END
```

SOLVED:

I solved the problem in another way
thanks anyway

I added to the car driver new value

an  Limo  - value Limo

an  Kombi - value LimoKombi

and Van   - value LimoKombiVan

and I solved using LIKE

```
SELECT
     fahrername
FROM
    fahrer
WHERE
     auto LIKE '%{typauto}%'
```

I think it's easier this way...
thank you anyway

Comment: You should post your solution in an answer and accept it, so others know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html)

```
set @vehType='Van'; 
select fahrername from fahrer where @vehType = 'Limo' 
    union select fahrername from fahrer where @vehType = 'Kombi' and auto in ('Kombi','Van') 
    union select fahrername from fahrer where @vehType = 'Van' and auto = 'Van';
```

Comment: I solved the problem in another way
thanks anyway

I added to the car driver new value

an  Limo  - value Limo

an  Kombi - value LimoKombi

and Van   - value LimoKombiVan

and I solved using LIKE

    SELECT
         fahrername
    FROM
        fahrer
    WHERE
         auto LIKE '%{typauto}%' 


I think it's easier this way...
thank you anyway